# Can the Eventful java client library be used for Android?

Tags: android, api

I am creating an app showing local events for android. I was hoping to use the Eventful API, since that came with its own java-based client library. However, I'm not sure if it's fit for Android, since I know a lot of these java based client libraries use stuff Android doesn't support.

So, does anybody know if it works?

My entire project is [available @ github](https://github.com/selbekk/eventually) if you want to check it out for yourself.

The [API is found here](http://api.eventful.com).

Comment: `An open sourced android application about showing local events to its users.` so, i guess, yes ?

Comment: No, that's my code. :-)

Comment: sorry, read too fast.

Answer (score 0):

Android does not have have issues with Java client libraries.  It is build on top of standard Java, and can use all of the framework features.

Furthermore, it looks like this API offers a RESTful interface, which is for sure supported by Android.

Bottom line, I do think you can use this API in Android without issue.

Comment: I thought the Android platform didn't support a few of the core libraries - ex. the javax-package -  usually available in desktop java applications.

I know I can implement my own API, but if they already have a client library finished, I might as well use that. Unfortunately, it doesn't look like it's working correctly. Pull the project via git and try starting it - it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the easiest way is to compile and run an application that embeds the library and tests a few methods.

Typically, you may have issues with the way the networking is handled. There are 2 main ways in android to do HTTP, the Java and the Apache way, I think the Java URL API is fully supported and very close to the actual Java version, but the Apache has some hidden differences.

The main risks you'll have are A/ that it uses classes or packages that are not present on Android. B/ that a class does not behave as expected, which does happen from time to time, as the Android implementation is entirely specific.

Apparently you have already tried to run an android app with the library included? Did you encounter a specific error? If you, can you post the stacktrace?